# swift parse/decoding multidimensional json array

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, decode

can any body help me to decode an multidimensional json array in swift.

json:

```
{
  "0": { "key":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value3" },
  "1": {"key":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},
  "2": {"key":"value","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a multidimensional array (there would have to be square brackets in your JSON for that). Just a simple map of maps. Please read up on the `Codable` protocol in order to get more useful things from you JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String:String]].self,from:jsonData)
```